# Day increase without datetime module in python

Tags: python, function, datetime, while-loop, module

I am the one who is studying algorithm about python!

While I am doing a fundamental thing regarding datetime

I can't figure out how to increase the date without datetime module.

What I have is that

```
lists = [[2021-03-08 3:00', '2021-03-08 4:00']]
```

If I have this schedule, and want to add daily schedule like

```
[[2021-03-08 3:00', '2021-03-08 4:00'], [2021-03-09 3:00', '2021-03-09 4:00'], [2021-03-10 3:00', '2021-03-10 4:00'] ...]
```

And I also have a second questions

I want to remove daily schedule If I call def remove_schedule

```
def remove_schedule
```

Is there any way to stop while-loop when I call function method?

Thank you!

If my questions do not make sense, please let me know!! and if it is, I am really sorry, will describe more about it!

Thank you guys for reading.

Comment: I'm assuming you have typos in lists you put on the question? lists = [[2021-03-08 3:00', '2021-03-08 4:00']] this is not valid.. its missing a '

Comment: So, if you were to have: `lists = [['2024-02-28 3:00']]` do you want to add on: `[['2024-02-29 3:00']]` or `[['2024-03-01 3:00']]`?

Comment: @Neeraj Opps that is my bad

Comment: @quamrana Yes, through while-loop. It will keep adding +1 days. That is what I want!

Comment: @quamrana One loop will add one day! 2024-02-28 3:00, 2024-03-01 3:00, 2024-03-02 3:00.....

Comment: If it adds exactly one day, what about `[['2024-02-29 3:00']]`? Don't you want anything to happen on that day?

Comment: @quamrana That might be fine!

Comment: I propose that you might want to know in advance whether your program will miss out a day every so often, so you might as well use `datetime` instead.

Comment: @quamrana I just do want to understand a fundamental algorithm :(

Comment: I suggest that dates and times are one area best left a solved mystery.